# Identical Macros Speed Difference

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I have 2 workbooks that contain the same macro. In one workbook the macro runs super fast, less than a second. In the other it takes almost 30 seconds to run. I'm using Excel 2003. The page breaks are off in both workbooks. I don't know what could be causing one to run slower than the other. Any ideas?

```
Sub viewFirst()
Dim dataSheet As Worksheet, inputSheet As Worksheet, projectID As Long
Dim projectRow As Long, lLastRec As Long, inputLastRow As Long, dataLastRow As Long, x As Long, sh As Shape
Worksheets("Input").Select
ActiveSheet.Protect "", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
Range("a1").Select
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert ("working.jpg")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
Set inputSheet = Worksheets("Input")
Set dataSheet = Worksheets("Database")
With inputSheet
    inputLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row - 1
End With
With dataSheet
    dataLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row - 1
    lLastRec = dataLastRow - 1
End With
With inputSheet
    .Range("currentProject").Value = 1
    projectID = .Range("currentProject").Value
    projectRow = projectID + 1
    For x = 1 To inputLastRow
        If Range("b" & x).HasFormula Then
            x = x + 1
        End If
        If x > inputLastRow Then
            Exit For
        End If
        If Not Range("b" & x).HasFormula Then
            .Range("b" & x).Value = dataSheet.Cells(projectRow, 2 + x)
        End If
    Next x
    .Range("d125").Value = dataSheet.Cells(projectRow, 2 + 149)
    .Range("d128").Value = dataSheet.Cells(projectRow, 2 + 150)
    .Range("d131").Value = dataSheet.Cells(projectRow, 2 + 151)
    .Range("d134").Value = dataSheet.Cells(projectRow, 2 + 152)
    .Range("d137").Value = dataSheet.Cells(projectRow, 2 + 153)
    .Range("d140").Value = dataSheet.Cells(projectRow, 2 + 154)
End With
With ActiveSheet
    For Each sh In .Shapes
        If sh.Type = msoPicture Then
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect ""
            sh.Delete
            ActiveSheet.Protect "", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
        End If
    Next sh
End With
Range("b5").Select
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

-EDIT-

osknows, thanks for the response. Just to clarify, the workbooks are never open at the same time, and again the workbooks are identical except for the data on the dataSheet - the dataSheet where the macro runs slowly has 35 Rows x 204 Columns, the dataSheet that runs quickly has 56 Rows X 156 Columns. I am going to search for hidden columns or non-blank cells on the input sheet.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the 2 workbooks it's difficult to tell. The best advice is to measure exactly the speed of your code by...

In a module decare

```
 Public Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
```

then in your code between certain lines of code place

```
dtStart = GetTickCount
dtline2 = GetTickCount
dtline3 = GetTickCount
dtline4 = GetTickCount 
..
etc
```

the number of ticks between dtStart and dtline2 equals `dtline2 - stStart` etc

Also a number of factors that could slow things down:

1. `inputLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row - 1` 
   could include many rows that seem blank but aren't.
2. `Set inputSheet = Worksheets("Input")` & `Set dataSheet = Worksheets("Database")` may be massive complex ranges
3. `For Each sh In .Shapes` could include many duplicate shapes over each other that look identical
4. You have undefined ranges & sheets that if you have multiple workbooks open and using them while code runs then workbooks/worksheets/ranges are not explicitly defined. (Eg .Range versus Range) Get into the habit of using the full path to a range Filepath/Workbook/Sheet/Range or cell etc using `With` statements

eg

```
With ThisWorkbook
  With SheetXYZ
     With .range("XYZ1")

     End with
  End With
End With
```

or

```
 With ThisWorkbook
  With SheetXYZ.range("XYZ1")
     .formula = "=Now()"

  End With
End With
```

Also check out this handy site [Excel Pages](http://www.decisionmodels.com/optspeed.htm)

Answer (score 0):

On the slower machine, unload any Add-ins.  If you have an add-in with a global change event, that will fire every time any worksheet changes, and could be causing the slow down.  You're writing to the spreadsheet quite a bit, so it would be called a lot.

Instead of writing cell-by-cell, consider building an array (2-dimensions, lower bound of 1) and write all the data to the cell in one big swoop.  Here's an example of how that works

```
Sub WriteOnce()

    Dim aReturn() As Double
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Const lLASTROW As Long = 10
    Const lLASTCOL As Long = 5

    ReDim aReturn(1 To lLASTROW, 1 To lLASTCOL)

    For i = 1 To lLASTROW
        For j = 1 To lLASTCOL
            aReturn(i, j) = Rnd
        Next j
    Next i

    Sheet1.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(aReturn, 1), UBound(aReturn, 2)).Value = aReturn

End Sub
```

Since I'm only accessing the worksheet once, any event handlers will only fire once.

Comment: Dick, thanks for the answer - they are both running on the same machine. Basically the macro is just taking x rows on the input sheet and transposing them to x columns on the data sheet.